# How does client know which wifi router to use?

Tags: wireless-networking, dhcp

I have two questions regarding my home network. It is currently set up as follows: Cable broadband -> NetGear CG3000v2 Modem (ssid:WIFI0) -> eth -> TP-Link WDR3600 (ssid:WIFI1) -> Netgear Router2 (ssid:WIFI1).

I have the two WIFI1 networks set to different channels, and Router2 is set to not deal with DHCP. I'm wondering:

a) As I move throughout my house, the relative signal strength will vary between the two WIFI1 routers. Does the laptop/phone/etc. connect via the strongest signal? If not, there isn't much point in what I'm doing really.

b) If I change the ssid of WIFI0 to WIFI1, is there any problem with that or will I just extend the range again?

Ta,
James

Answer (score 1):

a) If two WIFI1 set to different channels (eg 6 and 11) stations connect to strongest. But not reconnect until connection failed.

b) If You interconnect these routers by LAN ports (because home routers bridge wi-fi and LAN ports), and leave DHCP server enabled only at one. There no problem. It right extension of coverage.

Comment: Thanks. Is there any way to force it to connect to the strongest when I move around in coverage of both routers?

Comment: There no common way to force client to reconnect to other AP. If all ap on same frequency (channel) then client can switch to strongest AP as local roaming aggressiveness configured.
This is trade-of  between performance and mobility. Distributing AP by orthogonal channels (1,6,11)  You get performance for stationary clients.

Comment: Besides of it, on some AP You can force disconnection clients with low signal.

Comment: "Distributing AP by orthogonal channels (1,6,11) You get performance for stationary clients. " - is that good?

Comment: May be I Misunderstood question. If Wi-Fi network use 3 orthogonal channels. How mych performance You get? It can handle three times more clients without loose in performance.
In opposite, if all coverage (three AP) use same channel, You get more transparent roaming (client transition from one AP to other) for mobile clients.

Comment: Ah most things I read on the web seemed to suggest to use different channels so they wouldn't interfere. You think having them the same will work better?

Comment: Yes. But in this situation almost no interference mean no interoperablity. Station connected to one AP, know nothing about existence of other AP, and cant decide to switch (roam) to better AP.